# Visual Studio MVC 5 login without password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I use Visual Studio MVC 5 with the Account template that handles Login etc.
I want to Login as a user without a password. I tried this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

but then I get the Error that "UserId not found."

I created the user with this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
}
```

After that I was logged in and after I wanted to log in again I get this error.

---

Edit.: I know what is wrong.
`var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };`
also creates a new ID. I think this is not the right way to login..
The normal way to login is with `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);`
But there I need a password.
 How can I get loged in without a password?

Comment: Have you checked the database? has user been created?

Comment: Shouldn't the "Create" function also fail then if no user is saved? The User is stored in the database and has an Id.

Comment: It should, but as the error is saying UserId not found, I suggested to check it as it is very simple and gives you confidence that there is no problem with creating it.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: Why you need no password? You can use a password column but keep it empty so it solves your issue. To not having problem with validation you can develop a custom validation or simply hard code same password for all users when they create a user as well as when they login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object ApplicationUser has no id that's why you are getting this error.

try this:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
```

You could use too:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

After some try and error. You need to have the user as ApplicationUser with the right data like it is saved on your database. 
To get your user you need to do this:

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email).Result;
```

and this need to be passed to the SignInAsync function.