# How to allow empty passwords in ASP.Net MVC 5 with individual user accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, user-accounts

This might seem like a weird question, but I have a low security project that will only have a handful of users. Most of the users would definitely prefer not having to input password when signing in. I would like the ability to use password if wanted though. Similar to the way Windows 10 allows logging in without a password.

Any help with this would be great! I have currently removed the `required` annotation on the password property inside `AccountViewModels` but I am stuck at the point where it is throwing an error after I submit the register form.
[image: value cannot be null]

If anyone has ever done this before, I would love a few pointers.

Comment: search for `allowanonymous` attribute if you're not tracking who is doing what or alternatively use a differently security model - windows integrated

Comment: **You shouldn't for various reasons**, but If you realy want to bypass the Security Idenity provides, you could just bypass it, e.g. Have your custom User table and just use Session/Cookie to store the ID. No need for UserManager. Anyway, if you still need to use it, you could use some random password (e.g. `Guid.NewGuid`) for User Creation and [login with no password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52445850/2441442).

Comment: Can you not use the `UserManager.CreateAsync` overload that doesn't require a password when the password is null?

Comment: Can you explain @melkisadek? I think that is what I want, but not sure how.

Comment: You can create a random password and store it.

Answer (score 0):

you just put the Attribute [AllowAnonymous] on your Controller or your Action. The attribute is to allow access by non-authenticated users to individual actions

Comment: I will probably go with creating and storing a random password. Because I do need to know the username of the user during the session.